# How to mock named query in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking

I've following problem in grails 2.1.0. I've domain which has named query. In service I call list() method on result of this named query:

`List result = Domain.namedQuery(someParams).list()`

So, I'd like mock result in my service's unit test. Is there any option to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can through altering the metaclass.  Just be sure to `@Mock` the class as well so you don't get test pollution:

```
Domain.static.metaclass.namedQuery = { someParams ->
    // Assert and return data
}
```

Also be sure that you match the type and number of params exactly or it may not work.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work for me... What return's type should I use? When I try return `List` of domain class, then call `list()` on it, it returns empty List.

Comment: @ddd I think you need a PagedResultList.  I don't think a List itself has a method called list().